# request() not secure in Laravel with load balancer and TrustedProxies

Tags: laravel, load-balancing, laravel-forge

Why is `request()->isSecure()` returning `false` when visiting a HTTPS-url? I am using Laravel Forge and I have a load balancer. Logging the request I get this data:

```
request()->url(),          // "http://xx.xx"
request()->isSecure(),     // false
request()->getClientIps(), // XX.XX.XX.XX
```

In `TrustProxies` (which is added in the `$middleware` array in `Http/Kernel.php`):

```
protected $proxies = [
    'XX.XX.XX.XX', // exactly the same as in the logged data above
];
```

In my `AppServiceProvider`'s `boot()` method:

```
if (env('APP_ENV') == 'production') {
    \URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

**Edit:**

I am also using Cloudflare, and I have added all the Cloudflare proxies to `$proxies` as well. Check the logs, I see these headers in the request:

```
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
Cf-Visitor:        {"scheme":"https"}
Referer:           https://xx.xx/someurl
```

Comment: Likely that the request Laravel is seeing is between your load balancer and your web server which must not use https.

Comment: You should be able to forward headers with your load balancer but that is beyond the scope of SO.

Comment: If your load balancer is communicating with the webservers over HTTP instead of HTTPS, you'll see this behavior. Depending on the load balancer, there may be a `X-Forwarded-Proto` you can use to detect HTTPS.

Comment: In my log I can see `X-Forwarded-Proto: http`. What I didn't mention in my initial question, was that I also use Cloudflare. I did update the question with some more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While You are using Cloudflare You should to use "Full SSL/TLS encryption mode".